# como corrigir Recusa no Post de WebService

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Ao Enviar o Post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/CmisWebRequests.asmx/GetMessageResponse",
    data: dataToSend,
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    error: function(ex) {
        alert("EXCEPTION: " + JSON.stringify(ex));
    },
    success: function(resp) {
        var messageResponse = resp.d;
        $("#response").text(JSON.stringify(resp));
        $("#success").text(messageResponse.Success);
        $("#responseText").text(messageResponse.Response);
    },
    complete: function() {

    }
})
```

Recedo a negação

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

Como ceder essa permissão para determinado requisitante ?

Comment: A permissão deve ser realizada no back-end..qual linguagem está usando no servidor?

Comment: A linguagem usada no servidor é C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é uma proteção existente no Web Browser que bloqueia requisições em JavaScript(AJAX) que não sejam feitas a partir da mesma origem do seu site.

Isso vai acontecer se vc estiver rodando um JavaScript local e conectando numa API externa (outro site), se o servidor chamado estiver em porta diferente, se o host for diferente entre outras restrições.

A solução é o servidor mandar um header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Para permitir que requests sejam feitas a partir de outras origens.

Se vc não tem como mudar o servidor (solução) vc pode tentar as gambiarras abaixo:

1. Usar um proxy, que envie o cabeçalho acima,  pq aí vc requisita ao proxy e o proxy requisita a API
2. Remover manualmente o bloqueio CORS do seu browser (vc consegue fazer isso em modo Developer)
3. Usar internet Explorer ou Chrome, pois o Firefox é o mais rígido no CORS

Você pode tbem usar JSONP, mas aí depende do suporte que vc tem no servidor (de volta às origens)

Boa sorte

Answer (score 0):

No IIS a solução foi acessar o MENU Filtragem de Solicitações e atribuir o verbo POST na aba Verbos HTTP.

Comment: Que no final acaba mandando o header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *